# deploy VM Instance using deployment manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

Try to deploy the VM to custom VPC network called "MyNet" using deployment manager, just don't know how to put my custom VPC network in the yaml file, also want to use SSD instead of standard PERSISTENT disk as well.

```
   resources:
   - name: vm
    type: compute.v1.instance
    properties:
    zone: northamerica-northeast1-a
     machineType: zones/northamerica-northeast1-a/machineTypes/f1-micro
     disks:
   - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
     boot: true
     autoDelete: true
     initializeParams:
       sourceImage: projects/centos-cloud/global/images/family/centos-7
   networkInterfaces:
     - network: global/networks/default
    accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
       type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this example explaining how to create two VMs and a custom network with Google Deployment Manager](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/ced1b1f1/examples/v2/step_by_step_guide/step4_use_references/two-vms.yaml). In this repository, you can also find other examples that might be useful.

Anyway, for your specific problem : to create a custom VPC network, use :

```
- name: my-custom-network
  type: compute.v1.network
  properties:
    routingConfig:
      routingMode: REGIONAL
    autoCreateSubnetworks: true
```

Check [the REST reference of network resource](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/networks) to find all possible parameters.

To reference your custom network **and** also to use *SSD* instead of *Standard disk* for your VM :

1. reference the custom network in `networkInterfaces` section (`network: $(ref.my-custom-network.selfLink)`)
2. add the `disks.initializeParams.diskType` property in your VM configuration

To conclude, for your VM, you should write :

```
- name: vm
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
    zone: northamerica-northeast1-a
    machineType: zones/northamerica-northeast1-a/machineTypes/f1-micro
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: projects/centos-cloud/global/images/family/centos-7
        diskType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/zones/northamerica-northeast1-a/diskTypes/pd-ssd
    networkInterfaces:
      - network: $(ref.my-custom-network.selfLink)
        accessConfigs:
        - name: External NAT
          type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

For the disk, notice the `pd-ssd` at the end of the `disks[0].initializeParams.diskType` property, instead of `pd-standard` (default). Check the [REST reference of instance resource](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/instances) for other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify a `subnetwork` of custom VPC, That sit

```
resources:
- name: "vm-1"
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
    zone: {{zone}}
    machineType: zones/{{ zone }}/machineTypes/n1-standard-1
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: projects/centos-cloud/global/images/family/centos-7
    networkInterfaces:
    - subnetwork: projects/<project>/regions/<region>/subnetworks/<subnetwork_name>
```